# I don't know how to send the date from the js view to the laravel server

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

I run two servers, one for the frontend on which I use vue and another for the backend on which I run laravel.
I want to send the data from vue to laravel to enter it in the database using axios but I always get different sending errors (visible in the console) most often I get error 500 or 404 and I don't know where I'm wrong, I searched on google and no I found another answer and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Below I attach the code I use.

Code used in component for send data from vue to laravel server

```
 registerUser: function(){
                axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/userAdd', {
                    firstName: this.firstName,
                    lastName: this.lastName,
                    email: this.email,
                    password: this.password,
                    birthday: this.birthday,
                    headers: {
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                }).then((res) => {
                     console.log(res);
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                 });
            }
```

web.php :

```
Route::post('/addUser', [crudController::class, 'createPost']);
```

Controller:

```
class crudController extends Controller
{
    public function createPost(Request $request){
        $user = new Users();
        $user->firstName = $request->firstName;
        $user->lastName = $request->lastName;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->firstName = $request->firstName;
        $user->firstName = $request->firstName;
        $user->firstName = $request->firstName;
        $user->save();

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Record created!'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it! :D The problem is not the Cors, laravel return sometime cors error when something is not working in backend, for me was a path like

App\Http\Module\User but the correct path was App\Module\User that was the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

hey have you add this line please read this
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Comment: Yes, and it still doesn't work, I'm getting a Cors error.